# Access Webservice from another Application

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, web-services

I have an WebService in C# and I want to access this webservice from another application. 
Ex. Have one webservice running in localhost and i also have a website running in localhost, and this two projects are in diferents places. The question is: How do I invoke this webservice from my website with ajax, both in localhost.

The Code that i have is this: 
WebService

```
[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
public class Service1 : System.Web.Services.WebService
{
    [WebMethod]
    public String HelloWorld()
    {
        return "Hello World";
    }
}
```

and Client

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "localhost:52137/Service1.asmx?op=HelloWorld",
  contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
  dataType: 'json',
  data: '',
  success: function (data, status) {
      alert(data.d);
  },
  error: function(data, status){
      alert(status);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing url to this:

url: "http: //localhost:52137/Service1.asmx/HelloWorld"

And BTW.. if the website is running on a different port than the service.. you still have xdomain issues.

[CORS ASMX](http://encosia.com/using-cors-to-access-asp-net-services-across-domains/)

Answer (score 0):

As these two projects are in different places, it would be CORS request.

You need to enabled cross domain request in your service application as suggested in [this](http://encosia.com/using-cors-to-access-asp-net-services-across-domains/) article.

You can use [$.getJSON](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) which allow cross domain request.

As you're using C# you can create HTTP Handler as shown in [this](http://encosia.com/use-asp-nets-httphandler-to-bridge-the-cross-domain-gap/) article.